# Algorithm to permute elements in Array

Tags: algorithm, arrays, permutation

**Consider the following scenario**.

I have an array of numbers:

```
 [ 1,2,3,4 ]
```

If this array was joined i would have the number ***1234***.

I want to swap the numbers around to achieve the ***clossest higher number***.

***1234*** will become **1243**, which will become **1324**, which will become **1342** and so forth..

**What algorithm would i need use to make this changes in an array?**

Ideally i would like to use the algorithm in this manner:
 ( lets say Array has this algorithm as a function called walkthrough )

```
 [ 1,2,3,4].walkthrough() # gives [ 1, 2, 4, 3 ]
 [ 1,2,4,3].walkthrough() # gives [ 1, 3, 2, 4 ]
```

---

the list of numbers continues:

1234
 1243
 1324
 1342
 2134
 2143
 2314
 2341
 2413
 2431
 3124
 3142
 3214
 3241

Comment: Please continue the line of numbers. After 1342 I assume 1432 comes, and then? 4132 and then 4312 and then 4321?

Comment: I think there is an error in your list, shouldn't 2413 follow 2341?

Comment: yes... thanx... it has been fixed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This gives you next permutation:

```
bool Increase(int[] values) {
   // locate the last item which is smaller than the following item
   int pos = values.Length - 2;
   while (pos >= 0 && values[pos] > values[pos + 1]) pos--;
   // if not found we are done
   if (pos == -1) return false;
   // locate the item next higher in value
   int pos2 = values.Length - 1;
   while (values[pos2] < values[pos]) pos2--;
   // put the higher value in that position
   int temp = values[pos];
   values[pos] = values[pos2];
   values[pos2] = temp;
   // reverse the values to the right
   Array.Reverse(values, pos + 1, values.Length - pos - 1);
   return true;
}
```

Edit:
Changed Array.Sort to Array.Reverse. The items are always in descending order and should be in ascending order, so they give the same result.

Comment: do you have a Ruby equivalent to that Array.Sort part?

Comment: @Stefan: I have never used Ruby, so no. This overload of the Array.Sort method sorts the part of the array starting at the index in the second argument and the length in the third argument.

Comment: @paracycle: Thanks. Yes, it's C#. I invented it just now, or probably reinvented it... :)

Comment: Come to think of it, an alternative to sorting the part of the array is to simply reverse it. The items will always be in descending order and should be in ascending order afterwards.

Answer (score 6):

This looks like you want to generate *permutations* of your list in *lexical order*. Those search terms should start you on a useful path.

For instance, Python includes this in the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) module from version 2.6 on. That documentation shows code that implements such an algorithm.